# GlusterFs + zfs xattr

Tags: zfs, glusterfs, ubuntu-13.04

i'm trying to setup a small fileserver using GlusterFs over Zfs over two boxes that are currently running ubuntu 13.04.

i'm currently using glusterfs and zfs-fuse from ubuntu repositories and with those packages i've been able to create successfully a replicated gluster volume over xfs.

i've been also able to create zfs volumes with no issues at all.

The issuses starts when i try to create a gluster volume over a zfs path: 
after issuing the command

```
volume create apache-config-hosting replica 2 san1.local:/zfsroot/apache-config-hosting san2.local:/zfsroot/apache-config-hosting
```

i get:

```
2013 Sep  3 11:05:29 san1 [2013-09-03 11:05:29.962269] C [posix.c:4723:init] 0-apache-config-hosting-posix: Extended attribute not supported, exiting.
```

following advices from various tutorials i checked also xattr support with:

```
zfs get xattr
```

and i get

```
zfsroot/apache-config-hosting  xattr                 on                              default
```

which means that it sould be up and running. What am i missing?

EDIT: (adding content of /etc/zfs/zfsrc )

```
vdev-cache-size = 10
max-arc-size = 100
zfs-prefetch-disable
fuse-attr-timeout = 3600
fuse-entry-timeout = 3600
fuse-mount-options = default_permissions
```

Comment: Could you please share the file /etc/zfs/zfsrc?

Comment: hi, i've edited original post with the required info, thanks for help.
This config file has not been edited at all, btw.

Comment: What version of zfs fuse do you have installed? Could you try to put enable-xattr line to the aforementioned file and restart the service?

Comment: thanks a lot. adding enable-xattr from xfsrc made it stop complaining at volume creation. i'll do a couple of tests and then i'll mark reply as correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ZFS filesystem daemon is either configurable by passing it right command line arguments or by putting them to the configuration file `/etc/zfs/zfsrc`.

Version 0.7.0 of the daemon brought a new flag `enable-xattr` which enables support for extended attributes. Put this flag to the configuration file, restart the daemon and it should work. Keep in mind that the current implementation may cause a significant performance drop when  small IOPS are prevailing.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, it's quite misleading the fact that
 
    zfs get xattr

states they are **on** while they are not in reality.